# angularjs ngRepeat leaving html behind when template contains another ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller with an array of people **mainCtrl.People**.  Each person has an array of telephone numbers.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="people in mainCtrl.People">
    <ng-person data-json-pack={{people}}></ng-person>
</div>
```

The template for my person displays the name and the list of telephone numbers, and looks like this:

```
<div class="border">
    <p>{{personCtrl.Name}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="telno in personCtrl.TelNos">
        <p>{{telno}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I add an element to mainCtrl.People, a new directive appears.

When I splice out an element, most of the directive dissapears, but some bits are left behind:

```
<div class="border ng-isolate-scope">
     <p>{{personCtrl.Name}}</p>
     <!-- ngRepeat: telno in personCtrl.TelNos -->
</div>
```

I know angularjs can leave html comments behind, but in this case it is more than comments.  It is visible to the user as an empty border.

This happens when a repeated template has a repeat in it.  What am I doing wrong?

***Edited 9/9/2014***

Here is a plunker that demonstrates the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RQiMww1Rl8gzG6W5COuT?p=preview

The demonstration is a shop module with a list of products.  The button removes the last product from the list.  It only works once!

Comment: A bit more code would help. Can you link to a jsfiddle showing relevant bits, such as the controllers you're referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume -- and this is an **assumption** pending more information from your side -- that the binding to the directive is the problem.

You're probably doing something like

```
scope: {
  jsonPack: '@'
}
```

and from the looks of it, getting a string and unpacking the json from it? Again, not sure without more code.

Setting up a bi-directional binding like

```
scope: {
  jsonPack: '='
}
```

and getting an object directly (without converting to json for transportation) should solve your problems.

Also, you'd have to change your html to `<ng-person data-json-pack="person">` which would send your directive the entire person object as is.

Let me know if it works, or send some more information my way.

**EDIT:** In the above plunk, you're doing:

```
this.model.products.splice(this.model.products.length - 1, 1, null);
```

which means that you want to insert `null` in place of the last product removed. That will tell angular to try and render that last array item as a product. What you *should* do instead is:

```
this.model.products.splice(this.model.products.length - 1, 1);
```

which just means to remove the last element from the products array. The problem isn't in the rendering, its just in the model modification on your end.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Didn't solve my problem, but not I know how to pass json data without parsing it again.  I have added a Plunker to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: So, I just looked at your plunkr and I don't understand the reason behind wanting to add in `null` in place of your product. If you have the item in the array, angular will still try to render it. I edited my answer to propose a fix.